# HTML Email style not working in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I have a css property inserted inline to an HTML Email `text-transform:lowercase` to a span element. when I send the email it's shows the fonts are in lowercase except outlook. Seems the font styles are not applied in outlook. What is the correct way to insert the style inline which works for outlook as well?

```
<a><span style="text-transform:lowercase;letter-spacing:4px;">shop now</span></a>
```

*Outlook*

[image]

*Other Email Clients*

[image]

Comment: What outlook version are you using? Seems like Outlook is supporting `text-transform` https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @Justinas Yes. true. but still getting the issue. Using Outlook 2013.

Comment: Maybe try to pre-process text as much as possible before putting it in email?

Comment: Did you figure it out already @rifa_at_so ?

Comment: @Angel ofDemons  not yet.

Answer (score 2):

Since Outlook 2007 Outlook has used Word for its HTML formatting which means that Outlook doesn't allow all standard CSS. One example is text-transform. Someone else posted a link to CampaignMonitor.com which states that text-transform is supported by Outlook, but that is not the case. You can see for yourself on Microsoft's website under the section "Unsupported Cascading Style Sheet Properties Compared with Cascading Style Sheets, Level 1": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Generally Outlook [supports `text-transform`](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) as long as you put it in the right tag. That empty `<a>` tag could be throwing off outlook.

Try changing your code to this:

```
<a href="#"><span style="text-transform:lowercase;letter-spacing:4px;">shop now</span></a>
```

You can also place the inline styles right in the `<a>` tag and lose the `<span>` all together:

```
<a href="#" style="text-transform:lowercase;letter-spacing:4px;">shop now</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the value to lowercase before putting it in the email perhaps like this:

```js
   var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('text');
   var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('second');

    var res = MyDiv1.innerHTML.toLowerCase();

   MyDiv2.innerHTML = 'changed ' + MyDiv1.innerHTML + ' to ' + res;
       MyDiv1.innerHTML = 'Now you can use the variable `res` as a variable in the email';
```

```html
<span id="text">SHOP NOW</span>
<br />
<span id="second"></span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately. I can't use any scripts in the html page. just pure html and inline css. Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Not that I know of , because Outlook blocks _text-transform_ as far as I know. Can I ask why you cant use javascript at the top of your screen to set it as a variable?

Comment: It's a client requirement and I think we there is no other way to do this only using inline css styles. In that case may be your answer will help me to solve this.. Thanks!

Comment: My answer _does_  help you? Or not so much? If there is anything else you need just mention it and I'll try to edit my answer. Goodluck! And if the answer worked for you, accept it so other people who come here can see the correct answer

Comment: Since my requirement is to find a solution by using only inline css, I can't use script or external style sheet  so no point of trying your code at this level. Need to communicate to the client for a better solution like your one. may be your answer will help me once i get the client approval to use scripts in email pages. Anyway Thanks for the effort !

Comment: I dont know wat _source_  you use for email. But if you use _PHP Mailer_ You can just use variables in the email body like this for example:
`$mail->Body = '<td style="padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;border: 1px solid black;">'.$name.'</td>`

Comment: You cannot use any javascript or external css. They will be blocked by all email clients for security issues.